# Wi-Fi connection problem

Tags: 16.04, lts

The necessary wireless network is not showing in the Wi-Fi list , Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  , any help appreciated

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
Kernel driver in use: wl

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Sir, can you guide me

Comment: What is not clear? Run the mentioned command in terminal and post the output to your question.

Comment: how to add the output  Sir? I'm new to this , trying to learn

Comment: Open `terminal` application, paste the command there and press Enter key. Then copy the result and paste it to your question.

Comment: did sir as you said

Comment: It looks that the driver is installed. Please also add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: Please add new infromation to your question, NOT TO COMMENTS. It looks that your wireless adapter works well. I see no problems.

Comment: But i can see other Wi-fi networks , not mine

Comment: Click on "Other Networks".

Comment: you mean the hidden Wi-FI networks ?

Comment: I mean that you may not see all networks in the menu, if there are many networks.

Comment: even i tried creating the network again , but the Wi-Fi symbol of my network didnt show up (Wi-Fi was on )

Comment: If you try to connect to an existing network, you do not "create" it. What is "your wifi network"? Is it a router? What do you call "the Wi-Fi symbol of my network"?

Comment: yes it is a router , i mean to say the signal strength